# How to read Sheet of an excel file regardless if it's renamed?

Tags: vb.net

What I'm trying to do is to a converter. I'm having issues into opening an excel file since it's specified as [Sheet1$]. If the sheet has been renamed, my code is not reading it. Is there a way for me to get any name of Sheet perhaps?

```
Private Sub btnSelect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSelect.Click
    If cmbPortal.Text.Length = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Select portal to process first", "Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    Else
        Select Case cmbPortal.Text
            Case "Robinsons"
                FileFilter = "Portable Document File (*.pdf)|*.pdf"
                txtFilePath.Text = parse.showdialog(FileFilter)
                If txtFilePath.Text = Nothing Then
                    MessageBox.Show("No file was selected", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                End If
            Case "Waltermart"
                FileFilter = "Portable Document File (*.pdf)|*.pdf"
                txtFilePath.Text = parse.showdialog(FileFilter)
                If txtFilePath.Text = Nothing Then
                    MessageBox.Show("No file was selected", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                End If
            Case "7-11"
                Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
                With OpenFileDialog1
                    .FileName = "Excel File"
                    .Title = "Open File"
                    .InitialDirectory = "C:\User\Desktop"
                    .Filter = "EXCEL|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xlsb"
                    .FilterIndex = 1
                End With
                If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
                    Try
                        Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
                        Dim strConnString As String
                        strConnString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & FileName & ";"
                        Dim strSQL As String
                        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
                        Dim y As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(strSQL, strConnString)
                        y.Fill(RetVal)
                        txtFilePath.Text = FileName
                    Catch
                        MessageBox.Show("An Error Occurred, Please Contact MIS for Assistance", "SYSTEM", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                    End Try
                    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
                ElseIf txtFilePath.Text = Nothing Then
                    MessageBox.Show("No file was selected", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                End If
                Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        End Select
        If txtFilePath.Text.Length = 0 Then
            btnSelect.Enabled = True
            btnConvert.Enabled = False
            cmbPortal.Enabled = True
        Else
            btnSelect.Enabled = False
            btnConvert.Enabled = True
            cmbPortal.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the index of the worksheet you are retrieving fixed? For ex. is it always the first worksheet?

Comment: Your title is also misleading based on the content of your question.

Comment: It is always the first worksheet and based on the code, it is specified only if the first sheet is named Sheet1. What I wanted to do is to still read the first sheet regardless if it's renamed. I'm really sorry for the title and Thank you for noticing.

Comment: Check my answer. Kindly accept it by clicking the check button in my answer if it works. Let me know if it have some issues and welcome to the site btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim xlApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorkBook= xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName)

Dim SheetName As String = xlWorkBook.Worksheets(1).Name.ToString
```

Now that you have the sheet name, you can concatenate it to your `strSQL` like this one:

`strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SheetName & "$]"`

This will give you the first worksheet in the workbook.

Comment: wow thanks! it worked great! just that Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workook. Missing the "b" for workbook. thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. That was from my "stash" of codes and didn't even tested it before I posted it here. I'm glad that it helped. Happy coding!